# fcm Quotas and Limits per device and message

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, limits, quotas

I searched and read google documentation about this subject,
but I don't see good text about FCM. This [link](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) have pricing about all module exception cloud messaging,

My question :

How many device can register to fire base in free plan?

How many can send message per day in free plan?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no documented limits on the number of devices nor on the number of messages that can be registered in Firebase Cloud Messaging. This no-limits applies equally to both projects on paid and on free plans.